# Intercept all outgoing/incoming traffic on Linux using eBPF

Tags: c++, linux, docker, packet-sniffers, ebpf

I am looking for help with capturing all incoming/outgoing traffic on a host using eBPF across all containers. Need to identify from/to which container is the traffic coming. The filter should run on in a privileged docker container.

Don't need to receive the content, just the TCP/UDP headers are sufficient.

Comment: Can you add what you have so far?

Comment: I'm looking for options. eBPF is looking to be the best choice. Need some help with that.

Comment: Stack overflow is not the place to ask for recommendations (i.e it violates the rules). Can you reframe your question?

Comment: @RossJacobs done. this is pretty specific now. thanks.

Comment: You could check [Hubble](https://cilium.io/blog/2019/11/19/announcing-hubble/), which was just released.

Answer (score -1):

you can perform

```
tcpdump -i yourinterface
```

where yourinterface is the interface you need to monitor, as shown by ifconfig command

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. @rubenhak is asking for a C++ program, and `tcpdump` is a C program.

Comment: `system ("tcpdump -i yourinterface")`? or perhaps `popen`?

Comment: I need a eBPF implementation for this